# Show DisclosureGroup view based on state

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI, and I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the following issue I ran into. I have a button which toggles a state property, and I'd like to display a `DisclosureGroup` when the button's state is toggle on. For some reason, I can display any sort of view with my code below, with the exception of a `DisclosureGroup`:

```
@Binding var showing : Bool
@Binding var revealDetails : Bool

var body: some View {
    
    if showing {
        
        VStack {
            DisclosureGroup("Monday", isExpanded: $revealDetails){
                    Text("7PM - 10PM").frame(height: 100)
                }
            .frame(width: 150)
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).accentColor(.black)
                
        }
    }

}
```

}

The above code does not work when I present in my `ContentView`, however, the strange thing is, if I add some sort of empty view above the DisclosureGroup, it does work. So for now, I'm including a `Text("")` inside the `VStack`. Any thoughts on why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Preview Picture]

I think you're not passing correct values to your bindings, i can tell you clearly after seeing your code in ContentView as you haven't attached it in the question but you can copy paste below code and customise it depending on your needs.

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // MARK: - PROPERTIES
    
    @State private var showDiscloureGroup = false
    @State private var showDetails = false
    
    // MARK: - BODY
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Toggle("Show Disclosure Group", isOn: $showDiscloureGroup)
            Toggle("Show Details", isOn: $showDetails)
            
            MyDiscloureGroup(showing: $showDiscloureGroup, revealDetails: $showDetails)
        }//: VSTACK
        .padding()
    }
}

// MARK: - PREVIEW
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

MyDiscloureGroupView

```
import SwiftUI

struct MyDiscloureGroupView: View {
    
    @Binding var showing : Bool
    @Binding var revealDetails : Bool

    
    var body: some View {
        if showing {
            VStack {
                DisclosureGroup("Monday", isExpanded: $revealDetails){
                        Text("7PM - 10PM").frame(height: 100)
                    }
                .frame(width: 150)
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle()).accentColor(.black)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyDiscloureGroup_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MyDiscloureGroupView(showing: .constant(true), revealDetails: .constant(true))
    }
}
```